# Powershell to find a process's dll

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, process

I want to create a powershell program to find hidden possible powershells. Such as the project Not powershell NPS.exe found here (https://github.com/Ben0xA/nps).  a series of LS commands (thousands) and had it run.

I know that this application uses these libraries (System.Management.dll). I checked with process explorer and it confirmed but I ran this script as admin the script didnt pick up the libraries but did pick up other programs that were using the libraries.
What am I doing wrong? How would I found the dll? and why isnt NPS.exe dlls show in process explorer but not the below script.

```
#Possible Powershells
echo "Possible Powershells"
echo "-------------------------------------"
Get-Process | where {$_.modules.ModuleName -eq 'System.Management.ni.dll'}
Get-Process | where {$_.modules.ModuleName -eq 'System.Management.dll'}
```

[Process Explorer showing the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3luf.png)
[Powershell code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aOqa.png)

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @n8te sorry. Edit.What am I doing wrong? How come the powershell script only shows certian process using that dll and not others?  How would I found the dll? and why isnt NPS.exe dlls show in process explorer but not  in the script.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. Try rephrasing your question again and add clarity.